# Kotlin dagger hilt, how to reinit or delete/clear a serviceComponent

Tags: android, kotlin, service, dagger-hilt

I am new to dagger hilt and dependency injection in general.
I followed some exemples i could found and i manage to set up my application with hilt and it's woking perfectly. However i am using a serviceComponent in one of my activity to provide some database and from what i could understand provider is very useful because it's allow me to init and provide my data base when needed.
My problem is that i don't fully get how it's working right now. And i would like to be able to change my database but the provider seem to be called only one time so i can do that.
Here is my module :

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ServiceComponent::class)
object ServiceModule {

    @ServiceScoped
    @Provides
    fun provideMusicDatabase() = MusicDatabase(listOfSong)
}
```

This work the first time to provide my activity the MusicDatabase but when i try to change my listofsong, i don't know how i can notify my service that something has changed. So i would like to know if there is a way to reinit/delete/clear a ServiceComponent so i can update my database. Or maybe i am just using the wrong hilt tool because i am not really familiar with it ?

Also i would like to notifie that even when i finish my activity and it get destroyed, my ServiceComponent is not reinit when i reopen the activity. I am guessing that it's the normal behaviour but i'am new to hilt so i don't really know. So maybe i need to change annotation so it reset when i i restart the activity.
I also tried to change @ServiceScoped to @ActivityScoped for the MusicDatabase provider but it did not work.

So maybe i am just missing the whole point of hilt or i didn't get how to use it. But it would be very nice if i could get some help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly that's normal behavior, when you finish all activities `ActivityComponent` gets cleared, however since the service must not be stopped, so that both `SingletonComponent` (app-level) and `ServiceComponent` are kept alive. You need to make your Service standalone and exported, so it doesn't get stopped when there are no more bound clients (activities), then your activities will just bind to this Service.